# connecting ubuntu 12.04 lts to Windows network

Tags: 12.04, networking, windows

I am very new to Linux.  I have an existing windows network consisting of 3 windows 7 computers.  None of the computer user accounts have a password.
How do I connect to the network (including printer) from Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

You establish a network connection in one of two ways:

1. Plug in an Ethernet cable.  This method, you simply plug in the cable from the hub into the PC.  This is an older method, most modern PCs use wireless.
2. Wireless connect - find the wireless signal (top right, near the volume) then find the network you are trying to connect to ... select it, and enter your network key.

Now, once your computer is on the network; and assuming your printer is also on the network, you should be able to connect to it by pointing the computer at it (perhaps via the printer's IP address), and then installing drivers.  Printers are finicky, but connecting to the network is straightforward.